# C usual arithmetic conversions

Tags: c, integer

I was reading in the C99 standard about the usual arithmetic conversions.

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer
>   conversion rank is converted to the type of the operand with greater
>   rank.
>
> **Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank
>   greater or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then
>   the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the
>   operand with unsigned integer type.**
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the operand with unsigned integer type is converted
>   to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
>   corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

So let's say I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 10;
    signed int b = -5;

    printf("%d\n", a + b); /* 5 */
    printf("%u\n", a + b); /* 5 */
    return 0;
}
```

I thought the bolded paragraph applies (since `unsigned int` and `signed int` have the same rank. Why isn't b converted to `unsigned` ? Or perhaps it is converted to unsigned but there is something I don't understand ?

Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: What makes you think that `b` isn't converted to `unsigned`?

Comment: @Charles Bailey I guess I was foolishly expecting different results for the printfs :-?

Comment: +5 is +5, regardless of whether the int is signed or unsigned.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who helped (not enough rep to +1) :-)

Comment: @user963368: The format specifier that you pass to `printf` should match the type of the corresponding argument. The compiler is not going to tell you if you get that wrong. Besides, the result of addition is in the representable range of both `int` and `unsigned int` so it should have the same representation in both types.

Comment: Why -1 ? :-) Not the smartest question ever but not dupe, not homework, not badly written and **certainly on-topic**. I guess it's because downvotes on questions are free :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0x0000000a` plus `0xfffffffb` will always be `0x00000005` regardless of whether you are dealing with signed or unsigned types, as long as only 32 bits are used.

Comment: SO you mean it overflows and is reduced modulo `2^32` ?

Comment: It overflows, and the result is that it appears as though modulus has been applied.

Comment: Actually for the C standard overflowing with **signed** integers is undefined behavior (even if indeed today I would expect every hardware to use 2-complement representation for integers).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the C standard says that the behaviour on integer overflow is undefined. Only signed arithmetic *overflows* as per the standard. Unsigned arithmetic does *not* overflow, it is just always modular.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed `b` **is** converted to unsigned. However what you observed is that `b` converted to unsigned and then added to 10 gives as value 5.

On x86 32bit this is what happens

1. `b`, coverted to unsigned, becomes `4294967291` (i.e. `2**32 - 5`)
2. adding 10 becomes 5 because of wrap-around at `2**32` (`2**32 - 5 + 10 = 2**32 + 5 = 5`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly I don't have enough rep to +1.

Answer (score 3):

Repeating the relevant portion of the code from the question:

```
unsigned int a = 10;
signed int b = -5;

printf("%d\n", a + b); /* 5 */
printf("%u\n", a + b); /* 5 */
```

In `a + b`, `b` is converted to unsigned int, (yielding `UINT_MAX + 1 - 5` by the rule for unsigned-to-signed conversion).  The result of adding 10 to this value is 5, by the rules of unsigned arithmetic, and its type is unsigned int.  In most cases, the type of a C expression is independent of the context in which it appears.  (Note that none of this depends on the representation; conversion and arithmetic are defined purely in terms of numeric values.)

For the second `printf` call, the result is straightforward: `"%u"` expects an argument of type `unsigned int`, and you've given it one.  It prints `"5\n"`.

The first `printf` is a little more complicated.  `"%d"` expects an argument of type `int`, but you're giving it an argument of type `unsigned int`.  In most cases, a type mismatch like this results in undefined behavior, but there's a special-case rule that corresponding signed and unsigned types are interchangeable as function arguments -- as long as the value is representable in both types (as it is here).  So the first `printf` also prints `"5\n"`.

Again, all this behavior is defined in terms of values, not representations (except for the requirement that a given value has the same representation in corresponding signed and unsigned types).  You'd get the same result on a system where signed int and unsigned int are both 37 bits, signed int has 7 padding bits, unsigned int has 11 padding bits, and signed int uses a 1s'-complement or sign-and-magnitude representation.  (No such system exists in real life, as far as I know.)

Answer (score 2):

It is converted to `unsigned`, the unsigned arithmetic just happens to give the result you see.
The result of unsigned arithmetic is equivalent to doing signed arithmetic with two's complement and no out of range exception.

Comment: Are you talking about unsigned overflow ?

Comment: `unsigned` doesn't overflow (in terms of the standard) but just wraps around. This is well defined in the standard.