# explain the Outcome of C program

Tags: c, implicit-conversion

I saw following code which prints output **"Same"** but i am having trouble in understanding this program. Please help me to understand the program.

```
int  main() 
{ 
   unsigned int x = -1; 
   int y = ~0; 
   if(x == y) 
      printf("same"); 
   else
      printf("not same"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

How the output "Same" comes? Please help me about what happens here.

Comment: What is the result of `~0`? Please explain.

Comment: In addition to the bit equivalence of -1 and ~0, it may be good to note that the compiler does the "usual arithmetic conversions", converting ~0 to `unsigned int` type (explained e.g. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb.aspx)). The result of the comparison would be different it the numbers were converted to e.g. `int64_t`, but this is not what happens in c. A related question: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7544123/509868)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unsigned int x = -1 has the bit flags (32 bits) :

```
 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

int 0 has  the bit flags (32 bits) :

```
 00000000000000000000000000000000
```

~0 is the negate of 0 (bitwise) which is (32 bits) :

```
 11111111111111111111111111111111
```

As a side note :

```
 unsigned int x = -1;
```

is equivalent to

```
 unsigned int x = UINT_MAX.
```

Comment: I think the `#define` is `INT_MAX`... not `MAX_INT`

Comment: @Zeta Done . I didn't consider having the exact number of bits the core of the information . The idea behind it is for OP to understand the behavior of the bits.I find the difference of exemplifying over 14 bits or 32 bits irrelevant. However, I do find abelenky's comment is useful.