# size_t divided by int type conversion rules

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, literals

When I am doing arithmetic operations with size_t type (or unsigned long), how careful should I be with decorating integer constants with type literals. For example,

```
size_t a = 1111111;
if (a/2 > 0) ...;
```

What happens when compiler does the division? Does it treat 2 as integer or as unsigned integer? If the former, then what is the resulting type for (unsigned int)/(int)?

Should I always carefully write 'u' literals

```
if (a/2u > 0) ...;
for (a=amax; a >= 0u; a -= 3u) ...;
```

or compiler will correctly guess that I want to use operations with unsigned integers?

Comment: Why not simply `a / (size_t)2`?

Comment: @Eregrith: Because it is not "simple". It is difficult and ugly.

Comment: Reading about [integral conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_conversions) might help you.

Comment: @AnT What's difficult? Casting 2 to a `size_t`?

Comment: @Eregrith: Cluttering code that can easily be type-independent with an explicit type name is difficult at least because it makes one to step over that psychological barrier of "uglifying" the code. On top of that typing up the whole `(size_t)` where a mere suffix would suffice is generating more heat than light.

Comment: The naked `2` could use explanation.  If `2` was the result of the size of some object, then indeed it should be `2u` or better `sizeof(object)`.  Posting the context of use would provide answers a higher level understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`2` is indeed treated as an `int`, which is then implicitly converted to `size_t`. In a mixed operation `size_t / int`, the unsigned type "wins" and signed type gets converted to unsigned one, assuming the unsigned type is at least as wide as the signed one. The result is unsigned, i.e. `size_t` in your case. (See [Usual arithmetic conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544123/c-usual-arithmetic-conversions) for details).

It is a better idea to just write it as `a / 2`. No suffixes, no type casts. Keep the code as type-independent as possible. Type names (and suffixes) belong in declarations, not in statements.

Answer (score 5):

- The C standard guarantees that `size_t` is an unsigned integer.
- The literal `2` is always of type `int`.
- The "usual artihmetic converstions guarantee that whenever an unsigned and a signed integer of the same size ("rank") are used as operands in a binary operation, the signed operand gets converted to unsigned type.

So the compiler actually interprets the expression like this:

```
a/(size_t)2 > (size_t)0
```

(The result of the `>` operator or any relational operator is always of type `int` though, as a special case for that group of operators.)

> Should I always carefully write 'u' literals

Some coding standards, most notably MISRA-C, would have you do this, to make sure that no implicit type promotions exist in the code. Implicit promotions or conversions *are* very dangerous and they are a flaw in the C language.

For your specific case, there is no real danger with implicit promotions. But there are cases when small integer types are used and you might end up with unintentional change of signedness because of implicit type promotions.

**There is never any harm with being explicit**, although writing an `u` suffix to every literal in your code may arguably reduce readability.

Now what you really must do as a C programmer to deal with type promotion dangers, is to learn how the integer promotions and usual arithmetic conversions work ([here's some example on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312545/type-conversion-unsigned-to-signed-int-char/17312930#17312930)). Sadly, there are lots of C programmers who don't, veterans included. The result is subtle, but sometimes critical bugs. Particularly when using the bit-wise operators such as shifts, where change of signedness could invoke undefined behavior.

These rules can be somewhat tricky to learn as they aren't really behaving rationally or consistently. But until you know these rules in detail you have to be explicit with types.

---

EDIT: To be picky, the size of `size_t` is actually not specified, all the standard says is that it must be large enough to at least hold the value 65535 (2 bytes). So in theory, `size_t` could be equal to `unsigned short`, in which case promotions would turn out quite different. But in practice I doubt that scenario is of any interest, since I don't believe there exists any implementation where `size_t` is smaller than `unsigned int`.

Comment: I don't agree with all of this, but it is an excellent answer, plus one.

Comment: The result of the comparison is still `int`, but this is probably not what you meant ...

Comment: @JensGustedt Aah yeah the `>` operator is one of those special cases, I will edit. Thanks.

Comment: Btw it should be noted that the MISRA-C rule demanding that you write a `u` suffix on every single integer literal is probably the most debated and questioned MISRA rule of them all. Because in most cases the u suffix just clutters down the code, particularly when writing hex literals, as those are guaranteed to be unsigned anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Both C++ and C promote signed types to unsigned types when evaluating an operator like division which takes two arguments, and one of the arguments is an unsigned type.

So the literal 2 will be converted to an unsigned type.

Personally, I believe it's better to leave promotion to the compiler rather than be explicit: if your code was ever refactored and `a` became a signed type then `a / 2u` would cause `a` to be promoted to an unsigned type, with potentially disastrous consequences.

Comment: Wildly changing your type from size_t to a signed type is the dangerous practice. That's no fault of the `2u` literal. To omit the explicit type because you suspect that some monkey will maintain the code in the future doesn't sound like a valid rationale.

Comment: Rank of the types are involved.  Had it been a division of `int/unsigned char`, is not the quotient typically `int` as `unsigned char` is promoted to `int` first?

Comment: @chux Yes but how does that matter here, since there are no literals of character type in C?

Comment: @Lundin: having worked in the City for over a decade; there are plenty of refactoring monkeys ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't think you can make code monkey-proof. If someone who doesn't know what they are doing comes changing the code, then no coding practice in the world by the original programmer will save the program.

Comment: @Lundin This answer's "C promote signed types to unsigned types ..." does not not apply _in all cases_ as my earlier comments provides a counter example. Thus my attempt to qualify the overly general statement.   This answer's "C promote signed types to unsigned types ..."  does apply _in this case_ only because  ‘‘integer promotions’’ (which can change an `unsigned char/short` to `signed int`) need not  occur as `2` is already an `int/unsigned` and certainly `size_t` is already at least `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t sz = 11;

sz / 2 = 5

sz / (-2) = 0
```

WHY?
`sz` is treated as unsigned int because size can not be negative. When doing an arithmetic operation with an unsigned `int` and an `int`, the `int` is turned into `unsigned int`.

From "CS dummies"