# Ternary operator argument evaluation in C

Tags: c, logic, bitwise-operators, conditional-operator, misra

I've been working with some code to ensure MISRA compliance. The issue with this piece of code is

```
Operands shall not be of an inappropriate essential type. The operand of the ? operator is of an inappropriate essential type category unsigned.
```

I assume the issue is with the first argument being an unsigned data type, instead of boolean, which means the fix bellow would work.

The original,

```
 return (uint32Var & 0x80000000u) ? 0u : 1u;
```

My change to the code,

```
 return ( (uint32Var & 0x80000000u)!=0u ) ? 0u : 1u;
```

Is this a correct change to make? I'm concerned about changing the functionality of the code but as far as I know, at least in if logic, the operand is evaluated as `numVar != 0`  inside the `if ( numVar )` operator.

Comment: You could avoid the ternary operator altogether, e.g. `return 0 == (uint32Var & 0x80000000u);`. (I have no idea if that complies with the MISRA(ble) rules.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is safe.

You'll be comparing the unsigned 32-bit:

```
(uint32Var & 0x80000000u)
```

To the `unsigned int`:

```
0u
```

[Usual arithmetic conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544123/c-usual-arithmetic-conversions) apply to ensure that regardless of the actual types involved here, you'll be comparing values of types that are at least large enough to contains unsigned 32-bit.

The value `(uint32Var & 0x80000000u)` is a false one if it is equal to `0`, otherwise it is a true one. Comparing the value to `0` has the effect, and yielding `0` if the comparison is equal, otherwise yielding `1` is equivalent behavior.

---

As another note, the value that you end up using for the first operand of the ternary operator isn't a `bool`, it's an `int`. The `!=` operator yields an `int` value of either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume the issue is with the first argument being an unsigned data type, instead of boolean, which means the fix bellow would work.  /--/
>
> Is this a correct change to make?

Yes. As in, it will make the code MISRA compliant. The warning is indeed about using a non-boolean type for the 1st operand.

However, assuming that the function returns `uint32_t`, you may as well just write:

```
return (uint32_t) !(uint32Var & mask);
```

(`mask` since MISRA, like everyone else, discourages the use of "magic numbers".)

Equivalent and also MISRA-C compatible:

```
return ~uint32Var >> bits; // where bits in this case is 31
```

Normally the `~` operator is a nasty piece when writing MISRA compilant code, but it is perfectly safe when you use an unsigned integer type which is not a small integer type, such as `uint32_t`.